# invalid boolean exception in hibernate adapter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
 <bean id="sqlAdaptor"    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER"/>
    <property name="showSql" value="${showSql:false}"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="${generateDdl:false}"/>
</bean>
```

The above code throws an `Invalid Boolean Error` during application startup for

`{showSql:false} ->org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [boolean];`

The same bean config is working on other modules.

Comment: you know you can just set value="false" right?

Comment: ok. I do know that. i was trying to set a default value in case a property is not found. anyway ,it was because there was no property placeholder in the project. weird as it is , that is how spring works i guess.